# Using DC to draw wx.BitMapButtons on the fly?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm currently able to get this to do most of what I want to. It draws buttons based on lines from a text file as well as handles the way different button states look. What's really tripping me up right now is when `self.input` writes to the text file I have no idea how to get it to redraw everything to add or update buttons based on the new text. I've tried `Update`, `Refresh`, `Show (False)` then `Show(True)` and I'm stumped.

```
import wx
import mmap
import re

class pt:
    with open('note.txt', "r+") as Note:
        buf = mmap.mmap(Note.fileno(), 0)
        TL = 0
        readline = buf.readline
        while readline():
            TL += 1
    Note.closed

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        w, h = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        x = w * 0
        y = h - bdepth

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, pos = (x, y), size = (200,bdepth), style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", (6, pt.TL * 64 + 4), (184, 24))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnEnter, self.input)

        self.__DoButtons()            

        self.Show(True)

    def __DoButtons(self):

        Note = open('note.txt', "r+")

        for i, line in enumerate(Note):

            strip = line.rstrip()
            todo = strip.lstrip('!')

            self.check = re.match('!', strip)
            self.priority = re.search('(\!$)', strip)

            checkmark = wx.Image('check.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            bullet = wx.Image('bullet.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            exclaim = wx.Image('exclaim.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

            solid = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
            dc = wx.MemoryDC()
            dc.SelectObject(solid)
            solidpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(75,75,75),wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetPen(solidpen)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 64)
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
            dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bullet, 32), 10, 28)
            dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
            dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

            checked = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
            dc = wx.MemoryDC()
            dc.SelectObject(checked)
            checkedpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(50,50,50),wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetPen(checkedpen)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(200, 255, 0))
            dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(checkmark, 32), 6, 24)
            dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
            dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

            hover = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
            dc = wx.MemoryDC()
            dc.SelectObject(hover)
            hoverpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(100,100,100),wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetPen(hoverpen)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 64)
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
            dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bullet, 32), 10, 28)
            dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
            dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

            important = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
            dc = wx.MemoryDC()
            dc.SelectObject(important)
            importantpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(75,75,75),wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetPen(importantpen)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 180, 0))
            dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(exclaim, 32), 6, 24)
            dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
            dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

            importanthover = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
            dc = wx.MemoryDC()
            dc.SelectObject(importanthover)
            importanthoverpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(100,100,100),wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetPen(importanthoverpen)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 180, 0))
            dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(exclaim, 32), 6, 24)
            dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
            dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

            if self.check is None and self.priority is None:
                bmp = solid
            elif self.priority is None:
                bmp = checked
            else:
                bmp = important       

            b = wx.BitmapButton(self, i + 800, bmp, (0,  i * 64), (solid.GetWidth(), solid.GetHeight()), style = wx.NO_BORDER)
            b.SetBitmapDisabled(checked)

            if self.check is None and self.priority is None:
                b.SetBitmapHover(hover)
            elif self.priority is None:
                b.SetBitmapHover(checked)
            else:
                b.SetBitmapHover(importanthover)

        Note.closed

    def OnClick(self, event):
        button = event.GetEventObject()
        button.None
        print('cheese')

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        editnote = open('note.txt', 'r+')
        editnote.write(self.input.GetValue())
        editnote.close()
        self.Update()

bdepth = pt.TL * 64 + 32
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no point in calling `Update() Refresh()` etc by themselves. They won't auto-magically create your buttons, you need to do that.

For starters I would refactor your `__DoButtons()` into two methods, one  to create your buttons, and another to get your button data from your file and format it into an appropriate data structure  -a `list` (and process it accordingly if necessary) which you can then pass to your new `__DoButtons method (which does the actual button creation).

In your `onEnter()` you will need to call your `__DoButtons()` method and pass in the appropriate data, if you only need to add new buttons why don't you get the data directly from the `textEntry` widget and save yourself the hassle of reading it from the file.

Comment: Well that's good to know. I saw other people suggesting to use it in a way like that, but I likely missed something in their context since `Binds` looked auto-magical to me at first.

Alright, I'll start with that by extending `class pt` to actually create a `list`. Probably will be a lot more efficient as well as useful.

I'll read up on that and get back to this thread once I've made more progress.


Thank you.

Comment: This pretty much worked, it raised a few new problems, but only because of over sites on my part. Thanks again!